# Having issue understand what does this constructor do

Tags: c++

Can somebody please explain what's going on here? What is this constructor about? What is RetType? what does virtual mean? I am so confused. Please if it is possible to have some online chat help with you I would be more than happy.

```
class Traversal { 
public:
    virtual ~Traversal(){};
public:
    typedef enum {
        Stop, Continue, Skip,
        LastRetType
    } 
    RetType;
    virtual RetType pre(PDTAdd & d) { 
        return Continue;
    }


};
```

Comment: I think you can find out the answer by yourself, simply by getting a book of C++ for beginner.

Comment: I think you should follow the advice and find some good books or online tutorials, and systematically follow them. There are tons out there, like for example: http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/ or http://www.penguinprogrammer.co.uk/c-beginners-tutorial/classes/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly...

```
    typedef enum {
        Stop, Continue, Skip,
        LastRetType
    } 
    RetType;
```

...is a poor way of saying...

```
    enum RetType {
        Stop, Continue, Skip,
        LastRetType
    };
```

...which simply creates an `enum` type that can take on the listed values (`Stop` defaults to `0`, `Continue` to `1` etc..).

The `pre` function...

```
    virtual RetType pre(PDTAdd & d) { 
        return Continue;
    }
```

...then returns any of these values - above it hardcodes `Continue`.

It is `virtual` though, which means a derived class can write its own override of the function, and if someone has a `Traversal* p` or `Traversal& r` that actually refers to an instance of such a derived class, it will be the most-derived class that provides an override (if any) whose function is run by `p->pre(d)` or `r.pre(d)`.  This is known as *virtual dispatch*, and is the way C++ supports *runtime polymorphism*, which is one of the fundamental functionalities for Object Oriented programming.

Your next move should be a good book or tutorial.

Comment: thanks a lot! But Jerry was faster than you I am sorry :(

Comment: @KMass: `Traversal::Continue` is the same thing as `Continue`, just being explicit about the scope it can be found in.  I can't imagine any need to use it inside `pre`, but you might see some code outside `Traversal` (i.e. not in any member function of `Traversal`) use `Traversal::Continue`, so the compiler knows where to find it, and to ensure any other use of the identifier `Continue` (e.g. for a function name, variable, argument, type...) doesn't conflict.

Answer (score 3):

There is no constructor in your sample. There is:

- a destructor that does nothing.
- a definition of a type called `RefType`, so that variables can be defined of that type, instead of having to repeat the enum definition everywhere.
- a function that returns a value of the `RefType` type.

If you could define the enum as a type anywhere then the code would be the same as this:

```
class Traversal { 
public:
    virtual ~Traversal(){};
public:
    virtual enum { Stop, Continue, Skip, LastRetType } pre(PDTAdd & d) { 
        return Continue;
    }
};
```

See how the return type of the function is a huge enum?  Your sample gives that type the name `RefType` so that you don't need to repeat the enum definition everywhere that you declare a variable.  Defining the enum everywhere would be a bad thing to do so it isn't allowed by C++ - that's why typedefs exist.

Basically, because you can't create a new type (`struct`, `class` or `enum`) in a `return` statement directly, the enum is defined ahead of time as `RefType` and then `RefType` is used as the return type.

`RetType` is part of the `typedef` statement, it just spans multiple lines.  As a single line, it would look like this:

```
typedef enum { Stop, Continue, Skip, LastRetType }  RetType;
```

Comment: @KMass LastRefType is one of the values in the enum along with Continue and Stop and Skip

Comment: @DmitriBudnikov Yes it was.  but I didn't explain that it very well.  Please see the edit and tell me if you think it is still badly explained.

Comment: so RetType can be of type stop or continue or skip or lastrettype?

Comment: @KMass Variables of the type RefType can be assigned values of Stop, Continue, Skip, or LastRetType (the capitalization matters)

Comment: @KMass: You can't use a *value* from the enum directly in the function *declaration*, only in variable assignments, `return` statements, etc.  The function only has one *type* of return value (a `RefType`), but the *value* of that return can be any of the 4 values that are defined in the enum.

Comment: MAN YOU ROCK!!!!!!!!!!!!!! That last comment made everything clear to me, thanks a lot.

Comment: the comment of : "variables of the type RetType..."

Comment: @KMass  It is just like having the return type be int and then returning 0, 1, 2, or 3.  The type is RefType and the values of that type are one of the four values defined in the enum.

Comment: any idea what "return Traversal::Continue;" is returning? why not simply write: "return Continue" ?

Comment: @KMass If a class member returns it then the Traversal:: part is not needed.  If a global function is returning it then the Traversal:: part is needed because the enum is not global - it is part of the Traversal class.